# Angular route loading with async redirect

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-resolver

I need to wait for some API call before letting page in my route to load. Basically we have A/B testing enabled (which is API call) and based on that will have to either load Component assosiated with that route or redirect to different url.
To do that I was trying to use resolver that returns `Observable<boolean>`. Here is code:

```js
export class RedirectResolveService implements Resolve<Observable<boolean>> {
  private empty = new Observable<boolean>();
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.apiService.get("/api/abtest/mypage").pipe(
      tap((isOn) => {
        if (!isOn) {
          window.location.href = "/welcome-page";
        }
      }),
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

Then I add this in the route:

```js
{
  path: 'new-page',
  component: NewPageComponent,
  resolve: {
    redirect: RedirectResolveService,
  },
},
```

And then in NewPageComponent I add subscription in the constructor:

```js
export class NewPageComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.data.subscribe();
  }
}
```

It works but for the case when redirect happens I see first NewPageComponent rendered and then redirect happening. That makes sense since I subscribe to my Observable when Component initializes and thus only start redirect after that.

Is there way to make redirect logic without Component being initialized?

Comment: what if you used route guard instead of resolver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using route guard it would be something like this

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private _router: Router,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    return this.apiService.get("/api/abtest/mypage").pipe(
      tap(isOn => isOn || this._router.parseUrl("/welcome-page")),
      first()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about it but wasnt sure that canActivate method can return Observable